# java, Intellij IDEA и remote development

Tags: java, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi

Каким образом настроить компиляцию на удаленной машине java-приложения ?
В netbeans все достаточно просто и работает безотказно, а вот в intellij idea никак не могу разобраться. Найти в сети что-то внятное не вышло, в большинстве случаев все касательно web-a.
Зачем удаленная разработка ? Потому, что связка java+raspberryPi+pi4j.